# Search Bar with JSON Objects in TableView - Swift

Tags: json, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var recipeTable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchbarValue: UISearchBar! 

// search functionality

var filteredAnswers: [JSON]?


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){

    self.filteredAnswers?.removeAll()
    if (searchBar.text?.isEmpty)! {
        self.filteredAnswers = self.recipes     } else {
        if self.recipes.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...self.recipes.count - 1 {
                let answer = self.recipes[i] as [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                if answer.title.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                    self.filteredAnswers.append(answer)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    recipeTable.reloadData();
    recipeTable.reloadInputViews();
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}





//end search parameters


// tableview functionionalitys
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return recipes.count

}


// tableview functionalities
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeTableViewCell

    cell.recipeLabel.text = recipes[indexPath.row].title
    //cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.title
    //cell.imageView?.image = recipe.imageUrl

    return cell

}


// structs for json
struct Root : Decodable {
    let count : Int
    let recipes : [Recipe]
}

struct Recipe : Decodable { // It's highly recommended to declare Recipe in singular form
    let recipeId : String
    let imageUrl, sourceUrl, f2fUrl : URL
    let title : String
    let publisher : String
    let socialRank : Double
    let page : Int?
    let ingredients : [String]?
}

//recipes is array of Recipes
var recipes = [Recipe]() // array of recipes

//unfiltered recipes to put into search
var filteredRecipes = [Recipe]()




fileprivate func getRecipes() {

    let jsonURL = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=264045e3ff7b84ee346eb20e1642d9d9"
        //.data(using: .utf8)!

    //let somedata = Data(jsonURL.utf8)

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else{return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response , err) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode != 200 {
            print(response.statusCode)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let err = err{
                print("failed to get data from URL",err)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data  else{return}
            //print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                self.recipes = result.recipes
                //print(result.recipes)
                self.recipeTable.reloadData()
            }catch let jsonERR {
                print("Failed to decode",jsonERR)
            }
        }

    }.resume()

}



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //search functionalities

     self.searchbarValue.delegate = self

    //call json object
    getRecipes()
  } 
}
```

I am trying to implement a search bar that takes ingredients from the JSON Object and shows the recipes that contain those ingredients in my table view.  I am hoping for some best practices and help with this.  I have tried a couple different strategies and none seem to be working.

This is the last one I have tried to implement, but I am getting errors in the search functionality.

> self.recipes.count in searchBarSearchButtonClicked Cannot assign value
>   of type '[ViewController.Recipe]' to type '[JSON]?

But I'm also getting an assertion failure in -

> [UISearchResultsTableView
>   _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:]

I would like to get help but also improve and find the best way to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your logic to filter the recipes cannot work and is very, very inefficient. It seems you copied and pasted the code from a completely unrelated source.

Basically the type of the data source array and the type of the filtered array **must** be the same, so you have to use `filteredRecipes` rather than `filteredAnswers`.

To filter the recipes with matching ingredients use `filter` and `contains`

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){

    filteredRecipes.removeAll()
    if let searchText = searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
        self.filteredRecipes = self.recipes.filter { recipe in 
            guard let ingredients = recipe.ingredients else { return false }
            return ingredients.contains { $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
        }
    } else {
        self.filteredRecipes = self.recipes 
    } 

    recipeTable.reloadData();
    recipeTable.reloadInputViews();
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Actually this code is supposed to be executed in the delegate method

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

rather than in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`

And – very important – you have to add a boolean property to indicate `isSearching` and in all related datasource and delegate methods you have to add a condition to show the data of `filteredRecipes` if `isSearching` is true.

Comment: i am still having some issues.  When the search bar text is entered in the search bar, nothing happens.  If i declare the searchBar.delegate = self in the viewdidload method it only allows me to type 1 character at a time and still nothing updates.  I am using just the searchBar without  Search Bar Display Controller if I change this, it will refresh the table but there will not be any results shown. @vadian